# formating my problems so that I can write the problem number in latex?

Tags: formatting, numbering

Here is the format I want to do in document class book:

> [image]

Could anyone help me in fulfilling it please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which format do you mean? The box?

Comment: @Mensch all of the format, the title ,the name, the line below the name, the date, the exact number of the question, the box, I am using a different formate than this in general.

Comment: I even do not have the option of numbering my problems with chapter number, section number and problem number.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: @yo' I am just using overleaf this is why I put its tag.

Comment: @Happy Understood. However, in case the problem is independent of Overleaf, the tag is not really appropriate; it's useful only to mark issues that somewhat depend on Overleaf. Would that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, ok, no problem@yo'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example which is fairly similar to your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetstyle{mmddyy}
\DTMsetup{datesep=/}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[L]{\sffamily Name}
\fancyhead[C]{\bfseries MAT 7400: Homework 2}
\fancyhead[R]{\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{problem}{Problem}{
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colframe=black,
    coltitle=black,
    colback=black!10,
    colbacktitle=black!10,
    boxrule=.4pt,
    attach title to upper=\newline,
    sharp corners,
    top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    left=2mm, right=2mm,
}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \sffamily
    Title
\end{center}

\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\begin{problem}[phantom=\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{13}]{}{}
Prove that if \(\lvert G\rvert = 2k\) where \(k\) is odd then \(G\) has a subgroup of index 2. [Use Cauchy's Theorem to produce an element of order 2 and then use the preceding two exercises.]
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Since there are several elements that might seem complicated if you are new to all of this, here are some more details.

##### The header

The header is formatted with the commands from the [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package. It defines a page style `fancy`, which is customized in the example using the command `\fancyhead`. A similar command `\fancyfoot` could be used to set the footer. See the documentation of the package for more details.

##### The problem box

This kind of box is easy to do using the library `theorems` from the package [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), which is based on TikZ. The basic usage is through the command `\newtcbtheorem`, which works like the usual `newtheorem`, but with two additional arguments. The first of these accepts a list of keys and values to customize the look of the box. The second one is a prefix that will be used if you label the theorem to reference them later. Again, see the documentation for more details.

In the example, the `problem` environment is numbered within chapters and sections. I set the counters manually only to match the numbers from your example, but if you were to add a problem 4.2.14, for example, you could remove the calls to `\setcounter` when creating the next `problem` environment.